# Source Code for Completed Example Apps Built within ember.js Guides

Tags: ember.js

I am working through the [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/). I'm working through the "chat app" that they demonstrate throughout the Components section of the guides.

I'm currently on the [Looping through lists](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/looping-through-lists/) page and my app is breaking on me, so I'm trying to see if the completed application source code is somewhere that I can reference.

The closest I found was the [markdown of the guides themselves](https://github.com/ember-learn/guides-source), but not the source code in its entirety of this example "chat app" that is built throughout the Components section of the guides.

**Question:** Does the source code of the completed example "chat app", referenced in the Components section of the Ember guides, exist somewhere?

Comment: have a look [here](https://github.com/ember-learn/super-rentals)

Comment: @Lux thanks for the suggestion Lux.  That is a great one and it is the app for the official tutorial. The one I'm looking for is not the official tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug the issue I ran into.

Related to this question: it appears that at this time the example app for this section of the guides is not published anywhere.  [Here is my app](https://github.com/neil-unomaha/emberjs-Chat-Example) after working through the guides in case others find it helpful to reference.